# onTouchEvent() will not be triggered if setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) is invoked

Tags: android

I call

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
```

when my app starts to make my app able to display the full screen.

I want my app's UI to pop up when screen is touched, but `Activity.onTouchEvent()` is not triggered until the screen is touched a second time. At first touch, only the Virtual Keys are shown.

So, I have to trigger my app's UI to pop up on

```
public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
    if (visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) {
         // show my APP UI
    }
}
```

but `onSystemUiVisibilityChange` with `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE` will be invoked NOT once per touch (3 times on my Galaxy Nexus) by system, especially if the user touches the screen very fast/often.

project lib 4.0 or 4.03.
Samsung galaxy(9250) with 4.03.

Comment: I can also confirm this is happening.  Bug?

Comment: Me too. This I can't use the gestures on my video view.

Comment: At first touch, only the Virtual Keys are shown.----does your app's UI have  a EditText?

Comment: No. The problem is "only the Virtual Keys are shown". I need the under element's onTouch() be called, or at least don't call multiple times in a second touch.

Comment: Any update on this? I need onTouch() to be triggered as well. The first touch is consumed to show software keys.

Answer (score 9):

Android 4.4 (API Level 19) introduces a new `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` flag for `setSystemUiVisibility()` that lets your app go truly "full screen." This flag, when combined with the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flags, hides the navigation and status bars and lets your app capture all touch events on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This did work for me:

```
 setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0) {
                // show my app UI
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how does this help to react to the first touch event as described in the question?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is first imported `android.view.GestureDetector` so I can use it to detect gestures.  Android has a number of default gestures that are automatically detected in the [GestureDector class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html). Most of this info is found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html), but below is code in a form that I've used in an actual project that works.

First I've made an anonymous class in my Activity (this can be nested wherever, but I tend to make my anonymous classes at the bottom, right before the closing bracket).  NOTE: You can also implement `OnGestureListener` as part of your class, also.

The code below is for using gesture detection to give a simple hide/show.

I've declared and defined my action bar (my UI, which is initially hidden) as an instance variable, so I can access it here, and wherever else, but you can substitute it for a `getActionBar().show()` and `getActionBar().hide()` in the case you don't want to declare it as an instance variable.  Substitute your UI in the place of the `actionBar` here:

```
public class Example extends ActionBarActivity {

    // declared in onCreate() method
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar; 
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    private YourView view1;
    private YourView view2;
    private YourView view3;
    private YourView view4;

    // some other code

    class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures in Example Class";

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
            // if there is a double tap, show the action bar
            actionBar.show();

            return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());

            // if the tap is below the action bar, hide the action bar
            if (event.getRawY() > getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height)) {
                actionBar.hide();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {

             return true;

        }

} // end-of-Example Class
```

Then in my `onCreate()` I've declared my `GestureDetector` and also (optionally) set my `GestureListeners`:

```
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // some code here
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());

    // this code is for more advanced view logic not needed for a basic set-up
    //setGestureListeners();

} // end-of-method onCreate()
```

Then in order to actually send gestures to be processed we provide the instructions for doing that, there are two ways I know about, first the simplest:

```
/**
* This method recognizes a touchEvent and passes it to your custom GestureListener 
* class.
*/
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

     this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The second way is more complex, but if you want to only recognize touch events on certain `View`s in your layout as in the case where you have overlapping views and can only access the top `View`, you can create a custom class to pass the event around or up:

```
class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (v.equals(view4)) {
            return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);   
        } else return false;
    }
} // end-of-class MyOnTouchListener
```

and then use it here:

```
public void setGestureListeners() {

    /* when we return false for any of these onTouch methods
    * it means that the the touchEvent is passed onto the next View.
    * The order in which touchEvents are sent to are in the order they
    * are declared.
    */
    view1.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());

    view2.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());

    view3.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());

    view4.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());


} // end-of-method setGestureListeners()
```

In my `setGestureListeners` method, I gave them all the same set of commands, that essentially only recognizes touchEvents on `view4`. Otherwise, it just passes the touchEvent to the next view.

This is code using `AppCompat`, but if you are not building for older versions, you can use the regular `GestureDetector` and `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding code to only show your UI when the state has changed?  You have to maintain the last known visibility and only show your UI when you first come into being visible:

```
int mLastSystemUiVis;

@Override 
public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
    int diff = mLastSystemUiVis ^ visibility;
    mLastSystemUiVis = visibility;
    if ((diff&SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) != 0
            && (visibility&SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) == 0) {
        // DISPLAY YOUR UI
    }
}
```

Code sample adopted from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: I don't think you have understood the problem. This does not solve the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Activity.onTouchEvent()` gets called at the ***end*** of the responder chain (meaning after all other views have had a chance to consume the event).  If you tap on a view that is interested in touch (i.e. a `Button` or `EditText`) there's a good chance your Activity will never see that event.

If you want to have access to touches before they every get dispatched to your view(s), override `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()` instead, which is the method called at the ***beginning*** of the event chain:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //Check the event and do magic here, such as...
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    }

    //Be careful not to override the return unless necessary
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Beware not to override the return value of this method unless you purposefully want to steal touches from the rest of the views, an unnecessary `return true;` in this spot will break other touch handling.

Comment: This conceptually correct and good to keep in mind generally, but it fails in this specific problem. dispatchTouchEvent also didn't get called in the first touch when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too, and I found this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

So, no way to help. Even the android system packaged Gallery app used SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE instead of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION in photo page view. This is at least what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with trying to update the UI from an `onTouchEvent()` requiring two touches to work, and I tried a bunch of elaborate stuff before finally getting it to work on the first click.

In my case, I was showing a previously hidden item, then getting its height, then moving a button down by that height. The problem I ran into is that the height was showing as 0 until after the first touch event finished. I was able to solve this by calling show() during `ACTION_UP` for the `onTouchEvent()` instead of its `ACTION_DOWN`. Maybe it'd work if you did something similar?

Comment: This doesn't work if you need the position of the first ACTION_DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);

instead:

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)

After that you can use normal activity in fullscreen and if you want nav keys you need to swipe from bottom to up. Working for me at Galaxy Tab 2 with android 4.1.2