# ImageView inside Framelayout onclick only fired on second click

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

So I have search a lot of the solutions here on SO but none of them are working for me.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftFrame"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mark_as_complete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/immunisation_select_all_btn" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/markAllText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/mark_as_completed"
        android:textColor="@color/immunisation_button_text_color" />
</FrameLayout>
```

These are contained in a `RelativeLayout` which is in a `LinearLayout` all of which has the properties to disable focusable

This is the onclick code. It works only on second click

```
ImageView markAsComplete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mark_as_complete);
markAsComplete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Do something fun
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

I have tried the following, and still not working

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftFrame"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mark_as_complete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:src="@drawable/immunisation_select_all_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markAllText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/mark_as_completed"
            android:textColor="@color/immunisation_button_text_color" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftFrame"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mark_as_complete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/immunisation_select_all_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markAllText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/mark_as_completed"
            android:textColor="@color/immunisation_button_text_color" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftFrame"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mark_as_complete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/immunisation_select_all_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markAllText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/mark_as_completed"
            android:textColor="@color/immunisation_button_text_color" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that     `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` causes that the activity's first touch to be intercepted to display the navigation items again. I am now using     `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.Gone);` as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19799291/831371)

Comment: It is completely hiding my screen and showing a black screen. Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you disabled the focus for the ImageView? (just a thought)

Comment: Read some other SO posts on the subject and those posts said to add it, but even without those it doesn't work

Comment: maybe use `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: I don't think it is a clickable issue, because the onclick gets fired on the second click

Comment: I would have to disagree. If you [look here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com$java$ext@com.google.android$android@2.3_r1@android$view$View.java) you'll see that performing a click only happens after a set of checks to an object called viewFlags which has something to do with focusable states. I'm not gonna dive into this as I don't have the time, but I would however at least try enabling all the focus flags on the viewtree to see if that works out. if not, you can always go at it from a different viewangle. (talking mostly about re-enabling Focus)

Comment: I have edited the question, it is still not working, added clickable, and tested with turning focus on and off, it still only responds to the second click, and not the first at all

Comment: is the `setOnClickListener` called in the onCreate?

Comment: Yes it is called, because when I click it the second time it all works as expected, I have now also determined that touch events are also skipped on this imageview for the first touch and all touches after the first one is fired as normal

Comment: I have also now discovered it is happening on all activities, for an imageview, so lets say if there is two, and I tap one then all of them starts working correctly, I am now led to believe the imageview in itself has nothing wrong with it